$PO_{f_{n,1}}(\mathbb{R})(\text{Algebraic Group})=PO(n,1)(\text{Real Lie Group})$
Background: Consider the hyperboloid $I^n=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}:<x,x>=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_ix_i-x_{n+1}x_{n+1}=-1, x_{n+1}>0\}$
Let $O(n,1)=\{f\in GL(n+1,\mathbb{R}):\forall v,w\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}, <v,w>=<f(v),f(w)>\}$.
Then $PO(n,1)=O(n,1)/{\pm I}$
Want to show:
$PO_{f_{n,1}}(\mathbb{R})(\text{Algebraic Group})=PO(n,1)(\text{Real Lie Group})$ where $f_{n,1}=x_1^2+\ldots+x_n^2-x_{n+1}^2$
Reason from the notes:
The group $PO_{(n,1)}(\mathbb{R})$ is the image of the elements $g\in O_{f_{n,1}}(\mathbb{C})$ such that $\sigma(g)=\pm g$, where $\sigma$ denotes complex conjugation. Then if $\sigma(g)=-g$, it will have signature $(1,n)$, so a contradiction here. Thus, $\sigma(g)=g$. It follows that $PO_{(n,1)}(\mathbb{R})=O_{f_{n,1}}(\mathbb{R})/\pm I=PO(n,1)$.
Question: Why the group $PO_{(n,1)}(\mathbb{R})$ is the image of the elements $g\in O_{f_{n,1}}(\mathbb{C})$ such that $\sigma(g)=\pm g$? And how $\sigma(g)=g$ implies $PO_{(n,1)}(\mathbb{R})=O_{f_{n,1}}(\mathbb{R})/\pm I$?
Very appreciated to any help.
